# Calculating the greatest length of a polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, watershed, length

I'm new to QGIS and I need to know the easiest way to calculate the greatest length of a polygon. I already know the "rule" tool but I want to do it automatically because I have a huge amount of polygons to process. I only know the basics for the moment.

My polygons are watersheds and they look like this:
[image]

or even that:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What do you mean by "the greatest length of a polygon"?

Comment: You can check the centreline to get the longest length if that what you want

Comment: Kadir Şahbaz I mean "the biggest ax" or "the largest segment that fits in my polygon"

Comment: Gokul Anand thanks for your answer but it seems like this method is not automatic ( I just can't apply it on my watersheds one by one.) Am I right ?

Comment: Centreline tool is available in 'Geometric Attributes' plugin and u can use it to 'iterate' different feature classes from the dialogue box